# Issue with Flask-Sitemap after upgrading to python3.10

Tags: python, flask

I've just updated my python version to 3.10 and received following error:

```
from flask_sitemap import Sitemap
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sitemap/__init__.py:32: in <module>
from collections import Mapping
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/59636876/12368419

so you have two options:

1. downgrade your python to 3.8, not advisable
2. you can make a small tweak/patch/fix directly in the package source code in `venv/Lib/site-packages/flask_sitemap/__ init__.py` so have a look at this [discussion](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/issues/511) on github

change this line:

```
from collections import Mapping
```

to:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
```

Comment: There are already PR https://github.com/inveniosoftware/flask-sitemap/pull/48
So probably it will be merged soon.