# How to solve the error "AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping' when installing python 3.11.1 on Colab?

Tags: python, pip

I would like to install python 3.11.1 on Google Colab. However, when installing libraries I get the following error:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    vendored("pkg_resources")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 674, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 43, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 943, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'*
```

I've done the following setup:

```
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo apt-get install python3.11
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.11 1
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Then selected the right version. After that, when I execute:

```
!python --version
```

I get the correct version:

```
Python 3.11.1
```

Then, I installed pip using:

```
!sudo apt install python3-pip
```

I've tried the following:

1. Update the collections

   `import collections
   import sys
   if sys.version_info.major == 3 and sys.version_info.minor >= 10:
   from collections.abc import MutableMapping
   else:
   from collections import MutableMapping`
2. Install these packages


   `!sudo apt install python-pip
   !sudo apt-get update
   !sudo apt-get upgrade
   !sudo apt-get update`
3. Update the following packages:

   `!pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools requests`

My goal is to install these packages:

```
!pip install haversine
!pip install codecarbon[viz]
```

Comment: Not quite a duplicate but see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59636631/4996248

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work