# Troubleshooting ImportError: 'pymongo' in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, mongodb, import, jupyter-notebook, pymongo

Whenever I use to import the pymongo to my jupyter notebook it always shows an error

```
cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

Help me to get rid of this

I asked from gpt it told me to import many other modules like MutableMapping, abc etc but none of them are working!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59636631/importerror-cannot-import-name-mutablemapping-from-collections)